# Express.js send data to get request through post

Tags: node.js, express

I've a form with express.js:

```
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  if (req.body.something) {
    // Do something
  }
  res.send(myform);
});
app.post("/", function (req, res) {
  if (req.body.foobar == false) {
     // I need to set req.body.something and make it visible to "get"
  }}
});
```

My form:

```
<form method="post" action="/">
  <input type="checkbox" name="foobar">
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

I need a way to send data with "post" method and make it visible by the "get" method. How can I do?

Comment: Your POST and GET are asynchronous and discrete calls to the server.  There is no easy way for you to do what you're asking, other than to implement some logic whereby you execute your post with data, set that data into a variable on the server, and then once the POST returns complete on the client side, then execute the GET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably a number of ways to do this. One option is to store the POST values in a session.

```
app.post("/", function (req, res) {
  if (req.body.foobar == false) {
    //Store foobar from body of POST into the session
    req.session.foobar = req.body.foobar;
    // Other stuff...
  }}
});

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  if (req.body.something) {
  // Do something
     doStuff(req.session.foobar) // Here we use the foobar set in POST
     //DO MORE STUFF
  }
  res.send(myform);
});
```

To use this before add something similar to below enable sessions.

```
app.use(session({secret: 'fabecefd-387c-4dc9-a525-25d1fab00330'}));
```

More Documentation on  https://github.com/expressjs/session

Additional note: Please validate your input, handle error conditions, and structure your code your own way. The above was a very basic example on how to use sessions.

Comment: thank you, sure I do validate inputs, this is why I've posted this question :)

Answer (score 0):

```
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  if (req.body.something) {
    app.get('setKey');
  }
 res.json(req.body);
});

app.post("/", function (req, res) {
 if (req.body.foobar == false) {
   app.set('setKey','setValue');
 }}
});
```

Comment: is app.set a global variable shared by the entire app?

Comment: so it could cause problems with parallel requests... not a good solution

Comment: That doesn't happen. The app variable is the same as directly inputting the .get and .post methods directly to express. It just makes it possible to do so from various files across your project. That way you can have a dedicated folder for your routes, for example.

Answer (score -1):

You can send data with the GET method using jQuery :

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  data: 'Your body content here'
});
```

Or using curl from a terminal :

```
curl -XGET -d "Your body content" http://localhost:3000/
```

Comment: I'm developing using a REST api pattern... I need to use POST

Comment: I think I understood wrong, you want to set a req.body.something parameter for a future GET request, or you want the app.get function to be called after the app.post is done ?

Comment: I just submit my HTML form with POST method, then express get the POST request and the GET request and do some stuff.. I need a way to return some error if some of the POST values are wrong.

Comment: If you send your form via POST, express should only see a POST request, you can then return errors from the app.post method.

Comment: Looks like when I try to send some response through POST I get an error because GET has already sent his content.

Comment: Hard to say what could cause that without the code :s